# Unable to scp to and from AWS EC2 cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am unable to scp to and from ec2.
I type the following command: 
`scp -i ~/.ssh/my_key.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/models.pickle ~/`

I get the following warning:
`Warning: Identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/my_key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.`
`Permission denied (publickey).`

I also tried both `chmod 400` and `chmod 600`.

I am able to ssh into my cluster though.

I checked for the name of the pem file and it matches the one for my EC2 cluster too.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says the pem file is not found at the path you provided (~/.ssh/my_key.pem). Could you do a `cat ~/.ssh/my_key.pem` or `ls ~/.ssh/my_key.pem` to double check it's there?

Comment: It is there in my local drive. Do I need to copy it to my AWS Cluster too?